# A simple freeze behavior decorator

Tags: python, testing, decorator, freeze

I'm trying to write a freeze decorator for Python.

The idea is as follows :

**(In response to the two comments)**

I might be wrong but I think there is two main use of 
test case.

- One is the test-driven development : 
  Ideally , developers are writing case before writing the code.
  It usually helps defining the architecture because this discipline
  forces to define the real interfaces before development.
  One may even consider that in some case the person who 
  dispatches job between dev is writing the test case and
  use it to illustrate efficiently the specification he has in mind.
  I don't have any experience of the use of test case like that.
- The second is the idea that all project with a decent 
  size and a several programmers is suffering from broken code.
  Something that use to work may get broken from a change
  that looked like an innocent refactoring.
  Though good architecture, loose couple between component may
  help to fight against this phenomenon ; you will sleep better
  at night if you have written some test case to make sure
  that nothing will break your program's behavior.

HOWEVER,
Nobody can deny the overhead of writting test cases. In the
first case one may argue that test case is actually guiding
development and is therefore not to be considered as an overhead.

Frankly speaking, I'm a pretty young programmer and if I were
you, my word on this subject is not really valuable...
Anyway, I think that mosts company/projects are not working
like that, and that unit tests are mainly used in the second
case...

In other words, rather than ensuring that the program is 
working correctly, it is aiming at checking that it will
work the same in the future.

This needs can be met without the cost of writing tests,
by using this freezing decorator.

Let's say you have a function

```
def pow(n,k):
    if n == 0:  return 1
    else:       return n * pow(n,k-1)
```

It is perfectly nice, and you want to rewrite it as an optimized version.
It is part of a big project. You want it to give back the same result
for a few value.
Rather than going through the pain of test cases, one could use some
kind of freeze decorator.

Something such that the first time  the decorator is run,
the decorator run the function with the defined args (below 0, and 7)
and saves the result in a map ( f --> args --> result )

```
@freeze(2,0)
@freeze(1,3)
@freeze(3,5)
@freeze(0,0)
def pow(n,k):
    if n == 0:  return 1
    else:       return n * pow(n,k-1)
```

Next time the program is executed, the decorator will load this map and check
that the result of this function for these args as not changed.

I already wrote quickly the decorator (see below), but hurt a few problems about
which I need your advise...

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from collections import defaultdict
from types import GeneratorType
import cPickle

def __id_from_function(f):
    return ".".join([f.__module__, f.__name__])

def generator_firsts(g, N=100):
    try:
        if N==0:
            return []
        else:
            return  [g.next()] + generator_firsts(g, N-1)
    except StopIteration :
        return []

def __post_process(v):
    specialized_postprocess = [
        (GeneratorType, generator_firsts),
        (Exception,     str),
    ]
    try:
        val_mro = v.__class__.mro()
        for ( ancestor, specialized ) in specialized_postprocess:
            if ancestor in val_mro:
                return specialized(v)
        raise ""
    except:
        print "Cannot accept this as a value"
        return None

def __eval_function(f):
    def aux(args, kargs):
        try:
            return ( True, __post_process( f(*args, **kargs) ) )
        except Exception, e:
            return ( False, __post_process(e) )
    return aux

def __compare_behavior(f, past_records):
    for (args, kargs, result) in past_records:
        assert __eval_function(f)(args,kargs) == result

def __record_behavior(f, past_records, args, kargs):
    registered_args = [ (a, k) for (a, k, r) in past_records ]
    if (args, kargs) not  in registered_args:
        res = __eval_function(f)(args, kargs)
        past_records.append( (args, kargs, res) )

def __open_frz():
    try:
        with open(".frz", "r") as __open_frz:
            return cPickle.load(__open_frz)
    except:
        return defaultdict(list)

def __save_frz(past_records):
    with open(".frz", "w") as __open_frz:
        return cPickle.dump(past_records, __open_frz)


def freeze_behavior(*args, **kvargs):
    def freeze_decorator(f):
        past_records = __open_frz()
        f_id = __id_from_function(f)
        f_past_records = past_records[f_id]
        __compare_behavior(f, f_past_records)
        __record_behavior(f, f_past_records, args, kvargs)
        __save_frz(past_records)
        return f
    return freeze_decorator
```

- Dumping and Comparing of results is not trivial for all type. Right now I'm thinking about using a function (I call it postprocess here), to solve this problem.
  Basically instead of storing res I store postprocess(res) and I compare postprocess(res1)==postprocess(res2), instead of comparing res1 res2.
  It is important to let the user overload the predefined postprocess function.
  My first question is :
  **Do you know a way to check if an object is dumpable or not?**
- Defining a key for the function decorated is a pain. In the following snippets
  I am using the function module and its name. 
  ** Can you think of a smarter way to do that. **
- The snippets below is kind of working, but opens and close the file when testing and when recording. This is just a stupid prototype... but do you know a nice way to open the file, process the decorator for all function, close the file...
- I intend to add some functionalities to this. For instance, add the possibity to define
  an iterable to browse a set of argument, record arguments from real use, etc.
  Why would you expect from such a decorator?
- In general, would you use such a feature, knowing its limitation... Especially when trying to use it with POO?

Comment: You should elaborate on the *why*; it is not apparent why you would want this instead of unit tests.  -- Also, updating the .frz file when a function changes on purpose sounds like a pain.

Comment: "In general, would you use such a feature...?" Never.  Sorry, but this description makes little sense to me.  The use case is obscure.  Are you just pickling function results in a file?

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Let me answer in the main post.

Comment: @Deestan :
About the change, indeed it is a pain!!!
I don't know yet how to let the user "unfreeze" interface simply. (I can see one or two ways to do that though), if you have any smart idea about that I'd like to hear them as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"In general, would you use such a feature, knowing its limitation...?"**

Frankly speaking -- never.

There are no circumstances under which I would "freeze" results of a function in this way.

The use case appears to be based on two wrong ideas:  (1) that unit testing is either hard or complex or expensive; and (2) it could be simpler to write the code, "freeze" the results and somehow use the frozen results for refactoring.  This isn't helpful.  Indeed, the very real possibility of freezing wrong answers makes this a bad idea.

First, on "consistency vs. correctness".  This is easier to preserve with a simple mapping than with a complex set of decorators.

Do this instead of writing a freeze decorator.

```
print "frozen_f=", dict( (i,f(i)) for i in range(100) )
```

The dictionary object that's created will work perfectly as a frozen result set.  No decorator.  No complexity to speak of.

Second, on "unit testing".

The point of a unit test is **not** to "freeze" some random results.  The point of a unit test is to compare real results with results developed another (simpler, more obvious, poorly-performing way).  Usually unit tests compare hand-developed results.  Other times unit tests use obvious but horribly slow algorithms to produce a few key results.

The point of having test data around is not that it's a "frozen" result.  The point of having test data is that it is an independent result.  Done differently -- sometimes by different people -- that confirms that the function works.

Sorry.  This appears to me to be a bad idea; it looks like it subverts the intent of unit testing.

---

**"HOWEVER, Nobody can deny the overhead of writting test cases"**

Actually, many folks would deny the "overhead".  It isn't "overhead" in the sense of wasted time and effort.  For some of us, unittests are essential.  Without them, the code may work, but only by accident.  With them, we have ample evidence that it actually works; and the specific cases for which it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your point.

> The point of a unit test is to compare real results with results developed another (simpler, more obvious, poorly-performing way).

What about unit testing simple functions whose spec is partly conventional ?
e.g. Raising or return None for bad args

Comment: For a unit tests that's "trivial" (e.g., arg validation), you *are* working out the answer manually.  And the developing the result manually happens to be really easy.  But it's the same basic pattern of manually developing the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to implement **invariants** or post conditions?

You should specify the result explicitly, this wil remove most of you problems.

Comment: > Are you looking to implement invariants or post conditions?
Not really... This is more about checking that your function will behave the same in one year. But that's a nice idea. I use it already in another project.